# 'myservo' does not name a type

Tags: arduino-mega, servo

I keep getting *'myservo' does not name a type* as an error message, I have already looked other solved questions like this one but I can´t find the mistake. I would be very glad for your help.

```
/*********************************************************
 * Bot control
 * By soleil_zero
 * Based on code by
 * MSc. Fausto M. Lagos S.
 * @piratax007
 * V2.0.0 - 2019
 * GNU GPLV3+
 * 
 * Hardware:
 * Arduino Mega2560
 * Adafruit Motor Shield V1.2
 * Bluetooth module H6
 * 1 Servo
 * 2 DC Motor
 *********************************************************/

// Librería para Adafruit Motor Shield V1.2 y Servo
#include "AFMotor.h"
#include "Servo.h"

// Motores conectados en los puertos 1 y 2
AF_DCMotor leftMotor(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ);
AF_DCMotor rightMotor(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ);

Servo myservo;
myservo.attach(9);

// Variable para el paso de mensajes vía Bluetooth
char message;
//ángulo de rotación del servo
int angle = 0;

void setup() {
  // Velocidades en los motores
  leftMotor.setSpeed(150);
  rightMotor.setSpeed(150);

  /* Debido a que el Adafruit Motor Shield V1.2 ocupa los pines digitales 0 y 1 para la conexión del módulo HC05 
     bluetooth deben utilizarse cualquiera de los otros disponibles: 14 (TX3) y 15 (RX3) o 16 (TX2) y 17 (RX2) o
     18 (TX1) Y 19 (RX1). De acuerdo a cuál de los cuatro pines se utilicen deben modificarse las líneas
     relacionadas a la comunicación Serial e.g si se utilizan los pines 18 y 19 la instrucción será Serial1 */
  Serial3.begin(9600);
  myservo.write(angle);
}

void loop() {
  // Verificación de mensaje en el puerto Serial
  if (Serial3.available() > 0) {
    message = Serial3.read();
  }

 if (message == 'F') {//Forward
    leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
    rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
  } else if (message == 'B') {//Backwards
    leftMotor.run(BACKWARD);
    rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
  } else if (message == 'L') {//Left
    leftMotor.run(FORWARD);
    rightMotor.run(BACKWARD);
  } else if (message == 'R') {//right
    leftMotor.run(BACKWARD);
    rightMotor.run(FORWARD);
  } else if (message == 'S') {//stop
    leftMotor.run(RELEASE);
    rightMotor.run(RELEASE);
    Serial3.print("stop");
  } 
  } else if (message == 'U') {//down
    angle = 0;
    servo1.write(angle);
  }else if (message == 'D') {//up
    angle = 90;
    servo1.write(angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: this has been asked a lot ... please do research before posting your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and C++ languages we write statements *inside functions*. That `myservo.attach(9);` is a *statement*. You can't just write it in the middle of the file. It has to reside inside a function.

In your code `myservo.attach(9);` just sits in the middle of nowhere. You had enough sense to put `leftMotor.setSpeed(150);` inside `setup()`. Why did you suddenly decide to place `myservo.attach(9);` outside of any functions?

Function `setup()` would be an appropriate place for this statement.